# Unable to return values from a JSON file using JS/JQ for dynamically filling option boxes

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to write a basic conversion program for a site.  The category list is fairly extensive and after much searching online the best option seemed to be using JSON and Jquery, both of which are fairly new to me.

The aim is to use a drop down menu to pass a value to a PHP variable, depending on that variable a 'category' is chosen.  Within each of the categories there are sub categories and then within each of them are the various conversion units.

An example is "Basic" selected from menu with "Temperature" as the sub category.  The units would be C, F, K etc etc.  The user can then input a value, click the button and voila.

However...a; I'm hoping it's doable and b; I'm having problems with the JSON and jQ part.

An example of the JSON:

```
{
    "category" : "temp",
    "conversions":
    [{
        "value": "degC",
        "name" : "degC"
    },
    {
        "value": "kelvin",
        "name" : "kelvin"
    }],

    "category" : "area",
    "conversions":
    [{
        "value": "sqInch",
        "name" : "sqInch"
    },
    {
        "value": "sqYard",
        "name" : "sqYard"
    }]
}
```

I've tried many many different options and variations on code to try and access and return results.  The best I can get is whole a ton of [object Object] results or in the example below the last category is displayed fine.

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('JSON/conversionJSON.json', function(data){

        var output="<ul>";

        for (var i in data.conversions){
            output+="<li>Name: " + data.conversions[i].name + " :Value: "
            + data.conversions[i].value +"</li>";
        }

        output+="</ul>";
        document.getElementById("testJSON").innerHTML=output;
    });
</script>
```

is there something obvious that I'm missing?  I'd need this to be dynamic so not entirely sure how I'm going to accomplish that yet but if I can get one working then hopefully I can build on it. Any suggestions, help or advice is gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: You have repeated property names in the top-level of the JSON, that won't work. They'll overwrite each other. Are you sure it's not an array at the top-level?

Comment: so that explains why the last one is always being outputted. I think it should be an array.  Not sure how though.

Comment: Make the top-level an array similar to the conversions array. Or make the top-level an object whose properties are the category names, and values are the conversions.

Comment: @Barmar - I've just tried to amend the JSON file as you suggested but I'm still having difficulties.  I now get no output.  Can you update the JSON above to show what you mean please?

Comment: Take a look at face's answer, he's using the second method I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had done in one of my projects, first of all the JSON's schema you are using should be changed a bit. Your current schema doesn't put different `categories` into different JSON `objects`, so I came up with this new schema. The advantage of using it this way is you can reach the intended `category` just by calling `data['categoryName']`

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/87jnC/2/)

JSON:

```
{
    "temp" :    [
    {
        "value": "degC",
        "name" : "degC"
    },
    {
        "value": "kelvin",
        "name" : "kelvin"
    }],
    "area" : [
    {
        "value": "sqInch",
        "name" : "sqInch"
    },
    {
        "value": "sqYard",
        "name" : "sqYard"
    }]
}
```

Then the javascript part can easily be used just as following:

```
<script>
$.getJSON('JSON/conversionJSON.json', function(data){
    var list=$("<ul />");
    $.each(data, function(key, conversions){
        $.each(conversions, function(index, conversion) {
            $("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " + conversion.value + "</li>").appendTo(list);
        });
    });
    $("#testJSON").html(output);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you and thank you again, especially for saving me the homer like head scratching moment when the fiddle wasn't working :)

Comment: haha, yeah that was a logic fail.. sorry about that. happy I could help

Comment: Quick question:  Why have you used the elem in this example?  I stumbled across a few posts that suggest using an alternative.

I've got my dropdowns working nicely using your example.

I'm using : 

`if(key == "<?php echo $basic ?>"){

                            $("#from").append('<option value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');
                            $("#to").append('<option value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');`

where basic is the variable of the sub menu selected.

just not wanting to make mistakes before ploughing on.

Comment: Oh its just a variable, which is not being used anymore.. It should have been edited.  
Using just `$("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " + conversion.value + "</li>").appendTo(list);` or `$(list).append("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " + conversion.value + "</li>");` would work as well..

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
    "sEcho": "1",
    "iTotalRecords": 77,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 77,
    "aaData" : [
                    {
                "DT_RowId": "_79",
                "DT_RowClass": "orp",
                "0": "",
                "1": "<a href='/app_dev.php/orp/79'></a>",
                "2": "",
                "3": "",
                "4": "",
                "5": "Unknown",
                "6": "<a href='/app_dev.php/orp/79'><img src='/bundles/porotcore/images/icons/pencil.png' alt='Show' title='Show' /></a><a href='/app_dev.php/orp/79/disable' class='ajax'><img src='/bundles/porotcore/images/icons/cog_delete.png' alt='Disable' title='Disable' /></a>"
            },                    {
                "DT_RowId": "_78",
                "DT_RowClass": "orp disabled",
                "0": "",
                "1": "<a href='/app_dev.php/orp/78'>CONSEILLERS INACTIFS</a>",
                "2": "",
                "3": "",
                "4": "",
                "5": "",
                "6": "<a href='/app_dev.php/orp/78'><img src='/bundles/porotcore/images/icons/pencil.png' alt='Show' title='Show' /></a><a href='/app_dev.php/orp/78/enable' class='ajax'><img src='/bundles/porotcore/images/icons/cog_go.png' alt='Enable' title='Enable' /></a>"
            }
]
}

and in twig file,
{% spaceless %}
{
    "sEcho": "{{ sEcho }}",
    "iTotalRecords": {{ iTotalRecords }},
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": {{ iTotalDisplayRecords }},
    "aaData" : [
        {% for orp in orps %}
            {
                "DT_RowId": "{{ '_' ~ orp.id }}",
                "DT_RowClass": "orp{{ orp.inactive ? ' disabled' : '' }}",
                "0": "",
                "1": "<a href='{{ path('orp_show', { id: orp.id }) }}'>{{ orp.name }}</a>",
                "2": "{{ orp.customerId ? orp.seminarCustomer.getName : '' }}",
                "3": "{{ orp.telephone }}",
                "4": "{{ orp.fax }}",
                "5": "{{ orp.cityId ? orp.city.name : '' }}"            }
{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    ]
}
{% endspaceless %}


*I am not sure but use of i inside loop is required
for (var i in data.conversions){
         output = i.sth;`enter code here`
}

My json data and twig file may help you*
```